# Saved Images through Google Colab are not coming up in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am creating around 100000 images of 48*48 size and saving them to google drive through google colab but all the images are not coming up in drive.

Comment: Have you done this:

`from google.colab import drive`
`drive.mount('/content/gdrive')`

Then write like:

`with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/file.txt', 'w') as f:`
` f.write('content')`

Comment: Yes around 50-60% of the total images are getting but others are not getting updated.

Comment: Why don't you just save them to the collar firstly. Then: `!cp -r <PATH_TO_PNG_FOLDER> /content/gdrive/My Drive/` as you would do normally?

Comment: Also, there is also sometimes a bug in google collab which means you may need to force reload the mount via: `drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)`

Comment: If this still doesn't work you could try, before any other code, `from google.colab import drive` `drive.flush_and_unmount` which may take some time to execute but may work.

Comment: I might copied the folder directly but as the number of files is very large it was taking lots of time but finally I converted those into multiple zip folders then uploaded them and extracted in drive itself